# Saw you "talking" or "that you talked"

Tags: verbs, american-english, north-american-english

I always had a problem using right form of a verb/subject when it comes to describing an action performed by someone. What is the most common form of following in **conversations** .

*I saw you talking to him yestarday or I saw that you talked to him yestarday?* they clearly are not different forms of same thing but they describe  same action. 
*you try to impress people not caring about you or you try to impress people that don't care about you* .

I dont live in usa or other english speaking countries.  I need to emphesize that I'm not intreseted in how you write these correctly. I only want to know how the commom form of these are in oral conversation.

I see and hear people talking on tv ,mostly american series, and from what I see they don't talk the way I learned in school( well we just learned to write and speak like we are reading from a book ) Right or incorrent I would like to know how people say sentances above irl ( conversations )

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Payam, your Question is much too broad. Half a book could be written about What is *the most common form of following* in either conversations or writings, let alone both.

D’you think it might be easier, or more difficult to follow a detailed answer if you first got a study buddy to polish up the question?

It's hardly fair to talk about *the way I learned in school* when no-one here has any idea what you learned in school. Explaining the comparison in detail could be helpful…

D'you hear American TV as different from British or Australian?

The only way to find out how people on the street actually talk is to walk the streets and talk to people… or failing that to watch TV and movies.

If text books or internet forums could help, your question should first be broken down into half a dozen details and then taken to *English Language Learning*.

Just for instance, *Why not just answering the question* first needs amendment.

Then *I saw you talking to him* isn't ***another*** form of *I saw that you were talking to him* and neither of those is interchangeable with *I saw that you talked to him*.

Sadly, the English in your Question is several school years behind any useful answer; three or four, possibly five years if I remember my own schooling aright.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will try to improve my skills.